# Can reducer actions to be nested objects in redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm new to Redux and was wondering if you can nest actions in a hierarchy for readability like this:

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState: {
        data: {
            token: null
        },
        status: 'idle',
        error: null
    },
    reducers: {
        login: {
            requested: state => {
                state.status = 'loading';
            },
            received: (state, action) => {
                state.token = action.payload.token;
                state.status = 'succeeded';
            },
            failed: state => {
                state.status = 'failed'
            }            
        }
    }
});
```

As opposed to this:

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState: {
        data: {
            token: null
        },
        status: 'idle',
        error: null
    },
    reducers: {
        loginRequested: state => {
            state.status = 'loading';
        },
        loginReceived: (state, action) => {
            state.token = action.payload.token;
            state.status = 'succeeded';
        },
        loginFailed: state => {
            state.status = 'failed'
        }

    }
});
```

I don't know if this is a problem I just haven't been able to find an example of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not supported by the library - that's why you don't find any examples of it.

Source: I'm a maintainer ;)